# Google Cloud Speech API for MacOS

Tags: macos, google-cloud-speech

Is it possible to use the Google Cloud Speech API in a Mac app using something like AVAudioRecorder to record audio?

Comment: Since an API is just an interface that can be called with HTTP methods I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. Can you elaborate further your question?

Comment: Derp. My bad, I was confused because I was following the [iOS samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples), specifically the one that used gRPC streaming. You are right, and I don’t actually need streaming so I can follow their REST example. Thanks!